# Porting PHP Site to Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a really simple site in PHP / MySQL and JQuery http://mathalon.in/ , I am learning Ruby on Rails , its fantastic . I wish to port my existing site with data from PHP to Ruby on Rails.

I couldn't find any good solution. Any Help ?

Comment: That's a bit vague, isn't it?

Comment: Best way to do it - rewrite it from scratch. There is no any tool for converting PHP code to Ruby code. Also Ruby is very different in style. And Ruby on Rails uses MVC pattern as a basement. I think that your PHP site didn't use pattern at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely I mirror fl00r's response here, there's no magical "port from PHP to Rails" tool.  You'll need to do it manually.

Best thing to do first though, is to just write some simple Rails app yourself - just to get the hang of it.  Also using tutorial sites like [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) and [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) will really help.

Also, make good use of [the official Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and [the official Ruby on Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

**After** you've done your first simple app with the help of a tutorial, **then** take on the task of porting your PHP application.

Comment: What could be the more better way to port the data ( in database ) to Ruby on Rails. As its completely different from PHP.

Comment: There's no magic pill for that either, but using Rails to interact with legacy data structures is still much nicer than working in raw SQL in PHP.  You can accomplish most things for the legacy database with `set_table_name`, `set_primary_key` and the `:class_name` and/or `:foreign_key` options of the association methods.

Answer (score 0):

Jason King is right. You should first understand the rails way to handle the Database.
Then start porting the database, I guess, being a good in database, you can create various new database scheme or views, and then import the tables into your rails database.